# How to compute FFT point from sampling rate in audio recording

Tags: android, audio, signal-processing, fft, audio-recording

I have a sample code that fixed sampling rate, fft point in audio recording. This code is

```
private static final String FILE_NAME = "audiorecordtest.raw";
private static final int SAMPLING_RATE = 44100;
private static final int FFT_POINTS  = 1024;
private static final int MAGIC_SCALE = 10;
private void proceed() {
        double temp;
        Complex[] y;
        Complex[] complexSignal = new Complex[FFT_POINTS];

        for (int i=0; i<FFT_POINTS; i++) {
            temp = (double)((audioBuffer[2*i] & 0xFF) | (audioBuffer[2*i+1] << 8)) / 32768.0F;
            complexSignal[i] = new Complex(temp * MAGIC_SCALE, 0d);
        }

        y = FFT.fft(complexSignal);

        /*
         * See http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/audiofx/Visualizer.html#getFft(byte[]) for format explanation
         */

        final byte[] y_byte = new byte[y.length*2];
        y_byte[0] = (byte) y[0].re();
        y_byte[1] = (byte) y[y.length - 1].re();
        for (int i = 1; i < y.length - 1; i++) {
            y_byte[i*2]   = (byte) y[i].re();
            y_byte[i*2+1] = (byte) y[i].im();
        }

        if (handler != null) {
            handler.onFftDataCapture(y_byte);
        }
    }
```

That code is used to record raw file from audio recording. However, I want to change  `SAMPLING_RATE` to 16000. Could I used same FFT_POINTS is 1024? If not, Please suggest to me how to compute it and MAGIC_SCALE. I tried to used that values but the sound appear noise. Thanks.
The reference link is [here](https://github.com/steelkiwi/AndroidRecording/blob/master/lib/src/com/skd/androidrecording/audio/AudioRecordingThread.java)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The FFT algorithm doesn't care about the sampling rate.   I know that sounds somewhat non-intuitive, but each sample of the output (referred to as a bin) represents the magnitude of the content that is (SAMPLING_FREQUENCY / FFT_POINTS) Hz wide.

MAGIC_SCALE is just a value to scale the data and doesn't have a real impact when you're dealing with doubles.   If it were a DFFT using 16 bit integers, you'd have a scaling factor to ensure your input doesn't saturate/overflow during it's calculations.

Notice that the FFT function is never told what SAMPLING_FREQUENCY or MAGIC_SCALE is.

In the case of 44100, and 1024, each bin is the spectral content of ~43 Hz.  In the case of 16000, it's ~15Hz.

If 44100 works and 16000 doesn't, the problem is probably in the code that manages your audioBuffer[] variable.